# Reading JSON with APEX_JSON

Tags: json, oracle-apex

I've been trying to parse what I felt like a relatively simple JSON structure, but I'm having trouble doing it with APEX_JSON package.

```
create table sw_json (theclob clob);
insert into sw_json values (
'{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects(displayName)"
,"value":[
  {"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group","displayName":"Group A"}
 ,{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group","displayName":"Group B"}
 ,{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group","displayName":"Group C"}
 ]
}');
```

In a 12c environment, with the help of [Jon Dixon's](https://blog.cloudnueva.com/for-speeds-sake-stop-using-apexjson) post, I've been able to solve it in a variety of ways in SQL.

```
SELECT name
FROM sw_json
nested theclob.value[*]
columns (name varchar2(100) path '$.displayName')
;

SELECT name
FROM sw_json
left outer join json_table(
   theclob
 , '$.value[*]' columns (name varchar2(100) path '$.displayName')
) on 1=1
;

NAME     
--------
Group A  
Group B  
Group C
```

However, to make this also work in 11g, I've tried to do it solely with APEX_JSON. I succeeded with what feels like a sledgehammer method, but I was trying to tidy it up with more direct path expressions.

```
declare
    l_values apex_json.t_values;
    l_names  APEX_T_VARCHAR2;
    lc_clob  clob;
    lc_index varchar2(200);
    ln_cnt   number := 1;
begin
  select theclob into lc_clob
  from sw_json;

  apex_json.parse (
      p_values => l_values,
      p_source => lc_clob
  );
  dbms_output.put_line('Cnt:'||l_values.count);
  dbms_output.put_line('First:'||l_values.First);
  lc_index := l_values.First;
  for i in 1..l_values.count loop
    lc_index := l_values.next(lc_index);
    exit when lc_index is null;
    -- this seems hacky, relying on data content
    if substr(l_values(lc_index).varchar2_value,1,1) ='#' then 
      lc_index := l_values.next(lc_index);
      dbms_output.put_line(i||':'||l_values(lc_index).varchar2_value);
    end if;
    ln_cnt  := ln_cnt +1;
  end loop;
end;
    /

Cnt:12
First:"@odata.context"
4:Group A
6:Group B
8:Group C
```

I used jsonpath.com to validate my expression, but I can't seem to get it to translate to APEX_JSON usage - I can't help but feel I'm thinking about it incorrectly.

[image: validated json online]

```
declare
    l_values apex_json.t_values;
    l_names  APEX_T_VARCHAR2;
    lc_clob  clob;
    lc_index varchar2(200);
    ln_cnt   number := 1;
begin
  select theclob into lc_clob
  from sw_json;

  apex_json.parse (
      p_values => l_values,
      p_source => lc_clob
  );
  dbms_output.put_line('Cnt:'||l_values.count);
  dbms_output.put_line('First:'||l_values.First);
  dbms_output.put_line('Test:'||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => '$.value.[%d][displayName]', p0 => 1));
  lc_index := l_values.First;
  l_names := apex_json.GET_MEMBERS  (
       p_values => l_values
      -- tried all sorts of variations here to try match the 12c SQL
      ,p_path   => '$.value.[%d][displayName]'
      --, '$.value[*]' columns (id varchar2(100) path '$.displayName')
  );
  dbms_output.put_line('Cnt:'||l_names.count);
  lc_index := l_names.first;
  for i in 1..l_names.count loop
    exit when lc_index is null;
    dbms_output.put_line(ln_cnt||':'||l_names(lc_index));
    lc_index := l_names.next(lc_index);
    ln_cnt  := ln_cnt +1;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

No matter what I use for the path expression, I just get something the indicates to me the array returned empty.

```
Cnt:12
First:"@odata.context"
Test:
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
```

Trying a slightly different loop just returns 12 nulls

```
  for i in 1..l_values.count loop
    lc_str := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'value.[%d]displayName', p0 => i);
    dbms_output.put_line(ln_cnt||':'||lc_str);
    ln_cnt  := ln_cnt +1;
  end loop;
```

Comment: I think you should be using `'$.value[%d].displayName'`

Answer (score 1):

APEX_JSON does not use the "$." notation - that is implied. Following works. The `apex_json.does_exist` isn't really needed but it comes in handy to prevent the exceptions from being thrown.

```
declare
    l_values apex_json.t_values;
    l_names  APEX_T_VARCHAR2;
    lc_clob  clob;
    lc_index varchar2(200);
    ln_cnt   number := 1;
begin
  select theclob into lc_clob
  from sw_json;

  apex_json.parse (
      p_values => l_values,
      p_source => lc_clob
  );
  dbms_output.put_line('Member of value array:'||apex_json.get_count(p_path => 'value', p_values => l_values));
  IF apex_json.does_exist(p_path => 'value',p_values => l_values) THEN
     FOR r IN 1 .. apex_json.get_count(p_path => 'value', p_values => l_values) LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'value[%d].displayName', p0 => r, p_values => l_values));
     END LOOP;
  END IF;

end;
/

Member of value array:3
Group A
Group B
Group C
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to answer a few questions. I was close in the end, but something vital I was missing was explicitly passing p_values to apex_json.get_varchar2

Comment: However, what's wrong with my usage of apex_json.get_members, particularly if I use the adjusted path of 'value[*].displayName'? Instead of fetching them individually within a loop, I thought I could use this to return an array of results.